# buffer the spread of the virus

Tags: word-usage

buffer - to lessen or moderate the impact of something (lexico.com Dictionary)

(ex) The massage helped to buffer the strain. (the dictionary's example)

I have no questions about that example. I have made up the example below.

(1) Scientists have been trying to come up with a way to **buffer** the spread of the virus in the country.

Am I using the verb correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The verb is used correctly, but it would sound weird to a native speaker; "buffer" isn't often used as a verb anymore.

Something like "halt" or "slow" might work better.

Comment: Your explanation is clear and understandable. Thanks.